# How to avoid null values using MVVM in UWP project?

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I want to add new coffee details, when I add using `Addcommand` (custom command), but when add new details is `null`, so how do I avoid this issue?

Model class `Coffee`

```
public class Coffee : BindableBase
{
    private int coffeeId;
    private string coffeeName;

    public int CoffeeId
    {
        get
        {
            return coffeeId;
        }
        set
        {
            coffeeId = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CoffeeId");
        }
    }

    public string CoffeeName
    {
        get
        {
            return coffeeName;
        }
        set
        {
            coffeeName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CoffeeName");
        }
    }
}
```

View `CoffeeAdd.xaml`

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Coffee Id"/>
            <TextBox Width="120" Height="30" Margin="50 0 0 0" Text="{Binding CoffeeId}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 20 0 0">
            <TextBlock Text="Coffee Name"/>
            <TextBox Width="120" Height="30" Margin="20 0 0 0" Text="{Binding CoffeeName}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 20 0 0">
            <Button Content="Add" Width="120" Height="30" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="View" Width="120" Height="30" Margin="20 0 0 0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

ViewModel `CoffeeAddViewModel`

```
public class CoffeeAddViewModel:BindableBase
{
    private ICoffeeDataService coffeedataservice;

    public CoffeeAddViewModel(ICoffeeDataService dataservice)
    {
        coffeedataservice = dataservice;
        LoadCommand();

    }

    private int _coffeeId;
    private string _coffeeName;

    public int CoffeeId
    {
        get
        {
            return _coffeeId;
        }
        set
        {
            _coffeeId = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CoffeeId");
        }
    }

    public string CoffeeName
    {
        get
        {
            return _coffeeName;
        }
        set
        {
            _coffeeName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CoffeeName");
        }
    }

    public ICommand AddCommand { get; set; }

    private void LoadCommand()
    {
        AddCommand = new CustomCommand(add, canadd);
    }

    private async void add(object obj)
    {
        coffeedataservice.AddCoffee(new Model.Coffee { CoffeeId = _coffeeId, CoffeeName = _coffeeName });
        var dialog = new MessageDialog("Successfully Added");
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }

    private bool canadd(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I avoid the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the user input is not reflected in the `ViewModel` is because you have set up `OneWay` binding only.

```
{Binding CoffeeId}
```

This default syntax provides is `OneWay` - from `ViewModel` to `View`, in other words, property change in `ViewModel` is reflected in the `View`, but not the other way around.

To enable the data binding in both ways, you need to set the binding mode for both `CoffeeId` and `CoffeeName` properties to `TwoWay`:

```
{Binding CoffeeId, Mode=TwoWay}
```

Your XAML should then look like this:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Coffee Id"/>
        <TextBox Width="120" Height="30" Margin="50 0 0 0" 
                 Text="{Binding CoffeeId, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 20 0 0">
        <TextBlock Text="Coffee Name"/>
        <TextBox Width="120" Height="30" Margin="20 0 0 0" 
                 Text="{Binding CoffeeName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 20 0 0">
        <Button Content="Add" Width="120" Height="30" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
        <Button Content="View" Width="120" Height="30" Margin="20 0 0 0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```